# Impossible to reboot a machine over ssh

Tags: 18.04, server, shutdown, tty

My remote Ubuntu 18.04 machine got into a strange state. I tried to reboot it via ssh, but nothing helps: `sudo reboot`, `sudo shutdown -r -f now` both have no effect. The terminal comes back alive after some time as if I would had never entered the reboot command.

Same happens when I try killing defunct processes by both `kill -9` and `pkill`. None of them gets killed, they all continue to run. Trying to shutdown deamons like lxd or snap via `systemctl` ends with a *Connection timed out*. Just out of curiosity `apt update` fails for all sources with error messages like `Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'`.

Any ideas how I could force the system to reboot without physical access to the server?

Is such behavior known? I didn't find much of information except issues caused by wrong installation or configuration which does not seem to be my case. I suspect it is a result of running out of RAM while compressing a backup file in combination with two lxd containers doing their work at the same time... but I might be wrong. How could I check if this is not part of an exploit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force a reboot by switching to the root user and issuing the commands to:

1. synchronize: write data that is in the OS cache to disk
2. unmount: the file system to ensure it is safely removed before shutdown
3. reboot: issue a boot flag to force an abrupt reboot

   $ sudo -i

   ## echo s > /proc/sysrq-trigger

   ## echo u > /proc/sysrq-trigger

   ## echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you please elaborate more on synchronize data to disk an unmount file system? I never got so "low level" so why are these necessary? Can I reverse their effects if this goes wrong as well?

Comment: The "sync" will force any data in ram/cache to be written to the file system.  the unmount will ensure that the file system gets ready for a reboot event.  these steps happen during a regular shutdown.  So the state that your OS is in can't get any worse than it already is and it's possible that you have file system issues as it is.  A reboot will automatically remount the filesystem.  hence, these commands are not permanent nor dangerous.

Comment: Got it :) So after the last command the terminal hangs, but the ssh session seems to keep running. There is no sign of disconnection as typical after a reboot. Update: After opening a second ssh session `uptime` shows 3 mins. Looks like success!

Comment: it's an abrupt reboot, so the connection wasn't "closed" properly.  Hence, the ssh session hangs.  Are you able to reconnect?  If so, check the uptime:
$ uptime

Comment: Thank you very much, it rebooted!